# Jquery function that would return html() of passed div?

Tags: jquery

I have tried a couple of ways of doing this but didn't do well. I have a div in my HTML skeleton declared as ("myDiv"). I would like to write a function that would take any passed div as its argument and then return the passed div's html(). I can certainly write something like this and get the div text. But if I have a utility function which does nothing but reads the .html() and returns it then that would be great.

```
var txt = $("#div").html();
alert(txt);
```

Here is the function code:

```
$.fn.getDivHTML = function(obj)
{
   var txt = $(obj.html());
   return txt;
}
```

And I am calling the function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var val = $.fn.getHTML("#myDiv");
   alert(val);
});
```

Any help higly be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what's the point?

Comment: Why do you need to wrap the jQuery .html() function in a utility function? Just use the original function.

Comment: Well Daniel,if one has been well versed in Object-oriented implementations then there are tons of advantages of having such function. For instance, you have an animated div that slides from lets say top to bottom, for debug purposes, I wanna see its position top value as it is being animated. So as the div is sliding up, I am keep updating the position.top value in real time. just like a volume slider. This is just a very high level use, but there are tons of other useful things can be done with it. Write once and use as much as you desire. I hope you u understand the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a function like you describe this is the answer:

```
$.fn.getDivHTML = function(selector)
{
   return $(selector).html();
}
```

In your code you are only passing a selector string, not an object, hence the renamed parameter and the wrapping in `$()`.

You will be able to call this exactly in the way you have in your question. But as one commenter pointed out, what's the point? its a one-liner anyway. All you need to do is replace your doc ready with:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var val = $("#myDiv").html();
   alert(val);
});
```